# amCharts, non-numeric yaxis and dates

Tags: amcharts

I want to plot a graph between place and time. Y-axis will show 5 countries (USA, UK, Canada, France, Germany) and X-axis will show the time. The data is in pairs of (date, place). I am trying to display it by replacing the numeric values of Y-Y-axis with strings but no luck. Any simple working example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The value axis' [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#labelFunction) would be perfect for this task. With it, you can define a custom function that would be called for each label, which in turn could replace the number with a string. I.e.:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  // other value axis settings
  // ...
  "labelFunction": function(value) {
    var labels = {
      "1": "USA",
      "2": "UK",
      "3": "Canada",
      "4": "France",
      "5": "Germany"
    };
    return labels[value] || "";
  }
}]
```

---

Another option that you have is to disable value axis labels altogether ([`"labelsEnabled": false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#labelsEnabled)) and using [guides](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide) to place country labels at specific values. I.e.:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "labelsEnabled": false,
  "guides": [{
    "value": 1,
    "label": "USA"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "label": "UK"
  }, {
    "value": 3,
    "label": "Canada"
  }, {
    "value": 4,
    "label": "France"
  }, {
    "value": 5,
    "label": "Germany"
  }]
}]
```

Whichever works for your purposes better, or seems easier.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.